# Use custom model from legacy database to authenticate login django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Probably a very basic question.

How can i use my own legacy db table for authenticating login of the users in Django?

All the methods i am finding seem really confusing.

I want to use Django's own authentication system with modification of 'Persons' database table instead of 'User'.

Comment: You can create `Person` model that extends `AbstractBaseUser`, check this in Django documentation [Specifying a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Can you suggest the most painless and simple way to extend it?

Comment: Take a look at my answer bellow and let me know if it fits your needs.

Comment: Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of implementing custom authentication:

**person/models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class PersonManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')
        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')
        person = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )
        person.set_password(password)
        person.save()
        return person

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        person = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        person.is_superuser = True
        person.save()

        return person


class Person(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    # You may need to add more fields

    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = PersonManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

You will need to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'person.Person'` to your `settings.py` file (I suppose that your app name is person). Now, your authentification system will use `Person` model instead of the default `User` model.

For more details, check this tutorial [Extending Django's built-in User model](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#extending-django-s-built-in-user-model)